# How to show both Main Camera and FPV camera output in FPV Widget for Inspire 2?

Tags: dji-sdk

Android SDK: 4.8.1

I am using FPV widget with **Inspire 2** drone and only able to see the feed from Main Camera. How to show both Main and FPV camera output as in DJI GO 4 using FPV Widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UI sample includes the functionality in the sample.   I think that will be the best solution for your question.